# Give permission to a specific group without owning it

Tags: permissions, chmod

I have created a group named `newgroup`. But I didn't add my user to this group. Now I want give the `write permission` to this group for a specific file named `sample.txt`. I can use `chmod` if I am the member of this `newgroup`. Can I do this using sudo? How? I created this group using the following command

```
sudo groupadd newgroup
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, execute

```
sudo chown root:newgroup sample.txt
```

In that way you will change the owner of file `sample.txt` to be `root` and the group of this file to be `newgroup`.

Then run

```
sudo chmod g+w sample.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Will This chmod command change the permission for all groups or the groups related to my username?

Comment: With the first command, the file `sample.txt` will belong to the group `newgroup`, so the chmod command add write permission only to this group.

Comment: But still i can read/write the file from my user without sudo. I am not the member of newgroup. Nobody is the member of newgroup. I run chmod 775 simple.txt after chown :newgroup simple.txt. I should not be able to modify the file from my user. But i can. Because still i am the owner of this file. user field in chmod is unavailable

Comment: Is your user the owner of the file `sample.txt`?

Comment: Yes, i got it. it should be chown root:newgroup

Comment: That is, if you want root be the owner ot the file sample.txt.

Comment: Let's improve the answer a little bit...